# an error from template

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my code:

```
// head file
class JsonResponse
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void add(const string &, const T &);
};

template<typename T>
void JsonResponse::add(const string & name, const T & t)
{
    // do something
}
```

I compile it and get this error:
`error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Can you help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c91f8ce79eaa36bc

Comment: which line cause the error? are you using `using namespace std`? Because `string` is not prefixed.

Comment: @UmNyobe      `void add(const string &, const T &);` and `void JsonResponse::add(const string &name, const T & t)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a template error. you are using `string`, which is not resolved unless there is a `using namespace std` directive. You should be using `std::string` instead

Comment: omg.... I was cheated by Visual Studio again..... Sometimes the color hint doesn't work.... thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use template like this , it will work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class JsonResponse
{
    public:
       template<typename T>
       void add(const string &, const T &);
};

template<typename T>
void JsonResponse::add(const string & name, const T & t)
{
    std::cout<<name<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<t<<std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    JsonResponse jsonDbl;
    jsonDbl.add("nitendra",3);
    return 0;
}
```